# wscript exec cmd.exe /c does not report error

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd, windows-shell, wsh

I try several version of Wscript exec method.

If i use a cmd.exe /C MyRequest, the execution does not report an error if the MyRequest is failing but return the error if cmd.exe /c is not used.

I was thinking that cmd.exe is reporting the return code of the call to the MPyRequest but seems not. How to retreive the return code in this case.
Here is the simplified version of my test (comment direct version to have the non failure)

Environnement will be mainly windows 7 (normaly no other system, maybe XP)

```
' Missing.cmd does not exist to force the failure test

'version with cmd.exe (CmdDir content is a valid and working cmd.exe)
ExecCmd = CmdDir & " /c  Missing.cmd 1"

' direct version
ExecCmd = "Missing.cmd 1"

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

On Error Resume Next
Set oExec = objShell.exec( ExecCmd)

' -- Post treatment ---------------------------
If ( err.Number = 0) Then
   If ( oExec.ExitCode = 0 ) Then
        ' No error
         wscript.echo "Execution OK"
      Else ' Exit with error
        wscript.echo "Error :" & oExec.ExitCode
      end if
Else ' error on exec itself
   wscript.echo "Execution. Error on object at call: " & err.Number _
       & " Source: " & Err.Source & " Desc: " &  Err.Description
end if
```

---

**Solution** based on all your reply (thanks all) [ @Damien, @Ekkehard.Horner, @Hans Passant]

1. check error (via on error and err.Number) for vbs internal error like bad variable/method call. This should be at exec call sub level (so not at main process if exec call is in a function/subroutine)
2. exec.status to wait until it change to 1. Wait is a following process checking the status, not like a shell.sleep
3. during this wait, catch stdout/stderr with a AtEndOfStream if life info is needed (if not, read after the close of the process)
4. for a timeout process, use a cycle of shell.sleep with an exit (of cycle) if timeout or other event is trapped (I use a counter associate to a clock time/sleep time in this case) and exit the loop if trigger occur associate with a exec.Terminate to kill the process in this case (depending of your need ...)

Comment: So you are trying to establish if missing.cmd finishes with some kind of error? If that is the case, we are probably not going to be able to help you unless you show us what it is doing (inside missing.cmd). You could be returning an errorlevel of 0 for all we know.

Comment: in this case, as mentionned, missing.cmd does not exist and will create an error to execute. Tested in a direct command prompt it confirm the error, running the same command from exec method return no error nor return code > 0 and exec sttus is 0. So exec method return a correct execution but this is not the case. I suspect the call to cmd.exe (or exec method) to create a layer not transmiting the RC

Comment: You are probably processing exitcode before it finishes running. I'll add an answer in a moment.

Comment: You have to wait until oExec.Status turns to 1, indicating that the program completed and the ExitCode is accurate.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the [ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za76z6hh%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property.

Comment: sorry I simplify too much the code (reput the removed code including exitcode), exitcode was also used with same bad result.

Comment: What @Ekkehard mentioned 2 hours ago is still a correct answer. They have even linked to an article at Microsoft that tells you how to check the ExitCode properly.

Answer (score 3):

If it is actually returning an error code, perhaps you are processing exitcode to early. Maybe add in `oexec.StdOut.ReadAll()` to make it wait until completion.

Perhaps you could add in something like this

```
....
....
Set oExec = objShell.exec(ExecCmd)

oExecResult = oexec.StdOut.ReadAll() 
SessionExitCode = oexec.ExitCode     
' -- Post treatment ---------------------------
If ( err.Number = 0) Then
   If ( SessionExitCode = 0 ) Then
        ' No error
         wscript.echo "Execution OK"
      Else ' Exit with error
        wscript.echo "Error :" & SessionExitCode
      end if
Else ' error on exec itself

....
....
```

Comment: a step further, your are right without the read from stdout, it seems that process is too fast or missing something. Strange, because there is no StdOut content (in this case). Thanks anyway, i will continue using this way

Comment: If you feel this has answered your question, please consider accepting the answer as correct :) Have a nice day. :)

Comment: The link that @Ekkehard posted states: Executables set an exit code when they finish running. This conveys the status information when a process ends. Often, it is used to send an error code (or some other piece of information) back to the caller. `If the process has not finished, the ExitCode property returns 0`. The values returned from ExitCode depend on the application that was called.